# java.io.IOException: WSDL2Java emitter timed out (this often means the WSDL at the specified URL is inaccessible)!

Tags: axis, netsuite

i'm getting following error when i "deploy ant" on the terminal.
i found some answer like change "timeout to -1" .But i'm still wondering where to change the time .
Is it build.xml file of Axis?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the NetSuite Java Samples? In that case you need to look for a file called build.xml in the bin folder. This is the ant build script. Near the bottom there is a node called axis-wsdl2java. Add an attribute like so: timeout="120000" <- 2 minutes.